# If animals aren't getting tooth decay because they don't eat processed foods, could similar work for humans?

Tags: health, teeth

In [previous question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8997/what-is-dental-health-like-in-animals) here on stackexchange biology I read that animals don't get dental caries because they aren't exposed to refined carbohydrates like sugars. My question is: in theory, **could a human be completely dental caries-free if he followed the diet of not eating any processed food**? :))

And also, **are fruits** like apple or orange **'safe' against dental caries**? (since they're not 'processed' sugars?) Thank you kindly for answers.

Comment: What does "processed" sugar make bad? It comes in high concentrations and is ubiquitous, but else? It is purified (not more) from a natural source (either sugar cane or sugar beets). And natural products as pure apple juice can contain more sugar than a coke...

Comment: Chris, I'm not sure, but I in the previous question discussed here someone said that "plaque is colonised by acidogenic (acid producing) micro organisms cavities are produced in the presence of refined carbohydrates" and also "...besides wild animals are not exposed to refined carbohydrates like sugars.", hence "wild animals do not have these two diseases".

I don't really know much on this matter, that's why I'm looking for more answers.

Comment: Tooth enamel is almost entirely susceptible to acidity. So grass eating animals and fruit eaters have different issues.

Answer (score 2):

I think your assumption is wrong : Our small mixed breed had to have all her teeth pulled in 2 operations a year apart. The caries were so bad it damaged her kidneys.  i have had other dogs with caries but not so severe .

Comment: There is something missing from this: what was/is the dog's diet?

Comment: Her diet was the same, i expect, as most dogs in US, dry prepared dog food. Our other dog has excellent white teeth ( same food).